# Change TitleColor for custom UIButton (iOS 8 + swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have this custom UIButton class but I'm not able to change the titleColor for different states (normal, disabled, highlighted). I have already tried using `titleColorForState` to change it but it has no effect. Only thing that seems to work is `tintColor` but on different states the color simply fades and doesn't change.

Here is the code for my custom class:

```
import UIKit

class UIDefaultButton: UIButton {

    var normalBackground: UIColor { get { return UIColor.hrColors().whiteColor() } }
    var highlightedBackground: UIColor { get { return UIColor.hrColors().lightGreyColor() } }
    var disabledBackground: UIColor { get { return UIColor.hrColors().lightGreyColor() } }

    var normalTextColor: UIColor { get { return UIColor.hrColors().darkGreyColor() } }
    var highlightedTextColor: UIColor { get { return UIColor.hrColors().darkGreyColor()} }
    var disabledTextColor: UIColor { get { return UIColor.hrColors().greyColor() } }

    var cornerRadius: CGFloat { get { return 5.0 } }
    var borderWidth: CGFloat { get { return 1.0 } }
    var borderColor: UIColor { get { return UIColor.hrColors().greyColor() } }
    var hasBorder: Bool { get { return true } }

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            switch (highlighted) {
            case true:
                backgroundColor = highlightedBackground
            case false:
                backgroundColor = normalBackground
            }
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

        if (self.hasBorder) {
            self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor
            self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        }

        self.tintColor = normalTextColor
        self.backgroundColor = normalBackground
    }

    override func titleColorForState(state: UIControlState) -> UIColor? {
        switch (state) {
            case UIControlState.Normal:
                return normalTextColor
            case UIControlState.Highlighted:
                return highlightedTextColor
            case UIControlState.Disabled:
                return disabledTextColor
            default:
                return normalTextColor
        }
    }

}
```

Note: `UIColor.hrColor()` is my own extension for custom colors

Any idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
yourButton.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.hrColor()], forState: .Normal)
```

Make sure that you have a IBOutlet for the button and put this code in the  viewDidLoad()

Please give a +1 if this works for you!

Comment: I need it to be inside the custom class. Otherwise I'd have to be do this for every button in every view.

Comment: @shikhar.ja that's correct. It's the only way to do it. That's what I did. It doesn't take very long... Just some copy and pasting. Would you also mind taking a look at the question a posted and see if you know how to solve it?

Comment: I still want to figure out a generic way of doing this so I have kept this problem aside for now. I'll come back and update you on my solution once I have it figured out.